# Combine several columns with NA values in R, but only use NA if none of the columns has data

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I would be grateful for suggestions how to improve my code. The second attempt works and gives required output but I consider it very tedious. Perhaps there is a simpler solution to this.

The original dataset includes 8 columns containing information about screen resolutions. Each column represents a different set of questions into which participants were randomly allocated, this means that NA was inserted if the resolution question was not asked in that particular set, although participant may have answered it in different set.

I have anonymised and simplified data to include only three out of the original eight columns I am mentioning:

```
    ID  ResSet1 ResSet2 ResSet3
1   NA  NA  NA
2   NA  NA  NA
3   NA  NA  NA
4   NA  NA  NA
5   NA  1280x800    NA
6   NA  NA  NA
7   NA  NA  NA
8   NA  NA  NA
9   NA  1440x900    NA
10  NA  NA  1366x768
11  NA  NA  NA
12  NA  NA  NA
13  NA  NA  NA
14  NA  1366x768    NA
15  NA  NA  NA
16  NA  NA  1920x1080
17  NA  NA  NA
18  1600x1200   NA  NA
19  NA  NA  NA
20  NA  NA  1366x768
21  NA  NA  1440x900
22  NA  1680x1050   NA
23  1600x900    NA  NA
24  NA  NA  NA
25  NA  NA  1920x1080
26  NA  NA  NA
27  NA  1440x900    NA
28  NA  NA  NA
29  NA  NA  1600x900
30  1280x800    NA  NA
```

My goal is to combine all sets into one column called Resolutions; however, mark a particular row as NA only if it includes NA values in all of the sets/columns, if one set includes resolution, then only resolution values should be written into the column.

I attempted the following relying on dplyr and tidyr packages, here are my two attempts.

The first attempt using mutate and paste0:

```
x = test %>% mutate(Resolution = paste0(ResSet1, ResSet2, ResSet3))
```

This results in something like this: (output from original dataset)

```
    x$Resolution

1] "NANANANANANANA1366x768"  "NANA1440x900NANANANANA"  "NANANANANANA1344x840NA"  "NANANANA1366x768NANANA" 
      [5] "NA1280x800NANANANANANA"  "NANANANANANANA1366x768"  "NANANANA1366x768NANANA"  "NANANANANANA1536x864NA" 
      [9] "NA1440x900NANANANANANA"  "NANANA1366x768NANANANA"  "NANANANANANANA1280x800"  "NANANANANA1366x768NANA" 
     [13] "NANA1408x792NANANANANA"  "NA1366x768NANANANANANA"  "NANANANANA1920x1080NANA" "NANANA1920x1080NANANANA"
```

I did not figure out how to do something like rm.na function while using paste0 so in my second attempt using unite; I have replaced NA strings with "", and then replaced empty cells with the proper NA.

```
x2 = test %>% unite(Resolution, ResSet1, ResSet2, ResSet3, 
                     remove = TRUE, sep = "") %>% 
  mutate(Resolution = str_replace_all(Resolution, "NA", "")) %>%
  mutate(Resolution = ifelse(Resolution == "", NA, Resolution))
```

Result look like this:(output from original dataset)

```
x2$Resolution

"1366x768"  NA          "1280x800"  "1366x768"  "1366x768"  "1366x768"  NA          "1440x900"
```

This is actually what I need to achieve; however, the solution does not seem very elegant to me, and perhaps there is a simpler approach to this.

Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`coalesce` can be used to select the first non-`NA` value of respective values of several vectors:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(contains('ResSet')), as.character) %>%    # ensure all are character, not factor
    mutate(Resolutions = coalesce(ResSet1, ResSet2, ResSet3))    # coalesce

tail(df)
#>    ID  ResSet1  ResSet2   ResSet3 Resolutions
#> 25 25     <NA>     <NA> 1920x1080   1920x1080
#> 26 26     <NA>     <NA>      <NA>        <NA>
#> 27 27     <NA> 1440x900      <NA>    1440x900
#> 28 28     <NA>     <NA>      <NA>        <NA>
#> 29 29     <NA>     <NA>  1600x900    1600x900
#> 30 30 1280x800     <NA>      <NA>    1280x800
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily in base R - I assume that the first column is ID and all others are resolution columns:

```
df$res <- df[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), max.col(!is.na(df[-1]))+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Using:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:30, ResSet1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1600x1200", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "1600x900", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1280x800"), 
    ResSet2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "1280x800", NA, NA, NA, "1440x900", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, "1366x768", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1680x1050", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, "1440x900", NA, NA, NA), ResSet3 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1366x768", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "1920x1080", NA, NA, NA, "1366x768", "1440x900", NA, 
    NA, NA, "1920x1080", NA, NA, NA, "1600x900", NA)), .Names = c("ID", 
"ResSet1", "ResSet2", "ResSet3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

Then:

```
df$newcol <- 
  apply(df[,-1], 1, function(row) {
     if(all(is.na(row))) return(NA)
     else return(unique(row[!is.na(row)]))
  })
```

gives:

```
head(df)
  ID ResSet1  ResSet2 ResSet3   newcol
1  1    <NA>     <NA>    <NA>     <NA>
2  2    <NA>     <NA>    <NA>     <NA>
3  3    <NA>     <NA>    <NA>     <NA>
4  4    <NA>     <NA>    <NA>     <NA>
5  5    <NA> 1280x800    <NA> 1280x800
6  6    <NA>     <NA>    <NA>     <NA>
```

The use of `unique` here is motivated by the fact that even though there are no repeated observations per row in your example data, it might be the case in your actual data (as far as I understand your problem description). If that is not the case, you can omit `unique`. If there are two resolutions that differ, you may want to wrap it into e.g. `list` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a combination of `gather` and `right_join`. With this approach you don't have to specify all columns manually, in case your `data.frame` consists of just the `ID` and the other eight columns.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  gather(key, resolution, -ID) %>% 
  select(-key) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  right_join(df)
#> Joining, by = "ID"
#>    ID resolution   ResSet1   ResSet2   ResSet3
#> 1   1       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
#> 2   2       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
#> 3   3       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
#> 4   4       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
#> 5   5   1280x800      <NA>  1280x800      <NA>
#> 6   6       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
#> 7   7       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
#> 8   8       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
#> 9   9   1440x900      <NA>  1440x900      <NA>
#> 10 10   1366x768      <NA>      <NA>  1366x768
#> 11 11       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
#> 12 12       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
#> 13 13       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
#> 14 14   1366x768      <NA>  1366x768      <NA>
#> 15 15       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
#> 16 16  1920x1080      <NA>      <NA> 1920x1080
#> 17 17       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
#> 18 18  1600x1200 1600x1200      <NA>      <NA>
#> 19 19       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
#> 20 20   1366x768      <NA>      <NA>  1366x768
#> 21 21   1440x900      <NA>      <NA>  1440x900
#> 22 22  1680x1050      <NA> 1680x1050      <NA>
#> 23 23   1600x900  1600x900      <NA>      <NA>
#> 24 24       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
#> 25 25  1920x1080      <NA>      <NA> 1920x1080
#> 26 26       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
#> 27 27   1440x900      <NA>  1440x900      <NA>
#> 28 28       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
#> 29 29   1600x900      <NA>      <NA>  1600x900
#> 30 30   1280x800  1280x800      <NA>      <NA>
```